# Comprobar y reintentar conexión python

Tags: python, socket

Estoy haciendo un programa que establece conexión por el socket 4533 a un servidor y quería añadirle las funciones de detectar si se puede realizar la conexión antes de establecerla para que se cierre el programa y añadirle un bucle que reintente la conexión un numero determinado de veces.

```
import socket, time, select


# local host IP '127.0.0.1' 
host = '127.0.0.1'

# Define the port on which you want to connect 
port = 4533
address = (host,port)
print("Se va a establecer la conexión...\n")
FORMAT = 'ascii'

#Creamos el socket y lo conectamos por el socket 4533 a localhost
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
result_of_check = s.connect_ex(address)

def Client(): 

    while True:
        print("Conexion establecida")
        message = "P 180.0 0.0\r"
    
        # message sent to server 
        s.send(message.encode(FORMAT)) 
    
        infds, outfds, errfds = select.select([s], [s], [], 5)
        if len(infds) != 0:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if len(data) != 0:
                print('Received from the server :',str(data.decode(FORMAT)))        
        if len(outfds) != 0:
                print("Esperando...\n")
    
        time.sleep(5)
    # Close the connection 
    s.close()
    print("Un saludo")
      

def Comprobacion():
    
    if result_of_check == 0:
       print("Se va a establecer conexión...\n")
       Client()

    else: 
       print("No es posible establecer conexion\n")

    s.close()   

Comprobacion()
```

Lo he intentado repitiendo el bucle que comprueba la conexion pero me da el error de que entra en recursividad así que no se como plantearlo, ¿con un for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución conservando la mayoría del código.

Vamos a mover el chequeo de la conexión al final. El comienzo sólo declara variables.

```
import socket, time, select

# local host IP '127.0.0.1'
host = '127.0.0.1'
# Define the port on which you want to connect
port = 4533
address = (host, port)
print("Se va a establecer la conexión...\n")
FORMAT = 'ascii'
```

La función `Client` debe considerar la posibilidad de que el servidor corte la conexión, lo que produce una excepción `BrokenPipeError`. En tal caso, terminamos el proceso del cliente.

```
def Client():
    try:
        print("Conexion establecida")
        while True:
            message = "P 180.0 0.0\r"
            # message sent to server
            s.send(message.encode(FORMAT))

            infds, outfds, errfds = select.select([s], [s], [], 5)
            if len(infds) != 0:
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if len(data) != 0:
                    print('Received from the server :', str(data.decode(FORMAT)))
            if len(outfds) != 0:
                print("Esperando...\n")

            time.sleep(5)
    except BrokenPipeError:
        print("Servidor fuera de linea")

    print("Un saludo")
```

También eliminados el `s.close` dentro de `Client`. Como regla general, los recursos se devuelven en la mismo bloque donde se piden.

La comprobación la hacemos directamente, dentro de un ciclo `while` que admite un máximo de reintentos dado por `count`.

```
count = 3
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while count:
    if s.connect_ex(address):
        print("Servidor no activo ...")
        time.sleep(5)
        count -= 1
    else:
        Client()
        break

s.close()
```

Partiendo con un servidor inactivo, el cliente ve esto cuando el servidor levanta a los 10 segundos:

```
Se va a establecer la conexión...

Servidor no activo ...
Servidor no activo ...
Conexion establecida
Esperando...

Esperando...

Esperando...

Servidor fuera de linea
Un saludo
```

Comment: Buenas, entiendo entonces que la estructura quedará: 1º Declaracion de variables 2º Función Client() 3º Bucle while ¿no?

Comment: Claro, tal cual los pongo en la respuesta. Cortar-y-pegar.

Comment: Eso pensé, todo correcto.